# protect C:\wamp\www folder

Tags: windows, localhost, wamp, user-accounts

my lap top have two user account ex:u1 ,u2.
i want to giving full access in `C:\wamp\www` to u1 as a web programmer.  u2  as a client and he couldn't peep into C:\wamp\www folder. 
but he (u2)could viewing web site through web browser. ex`:http://localhost/group11/index.php`
how to do this?,is that windows user managment task or apache server configuration task.

Comment: And where is question?

Comment: oh! sorry. pls see it again.i added it